# C# get multiple rows from list where

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list `List<row>rows = new List<row>();` that containing 500 rows.

Each row contain a values:  `tableID`, `rowLabelID`

`rowLabelID` increases each 13th row

How can I get each row where `tableId == "122"` and `rowLabelID == "1"`

This is what I got, but it does not seem to work.

```
var rows_output = rows.Where(x => x.TableID == tableID && x.rowLabelId == "1");
```

Comment: what does `does not seem to work` mean?

Comment: Describe what's wrong with your code. Otherwise there's nothing we can do. What is the desired result at all? Maybe you want a `List<List<row>>` where each inner list contains the 13 rows.

Comment: Mb typo `rowLabelID`  -  `x.rowLabelId`?

Comment: Can you show us `row` class definition

Comment: var rows_output = rows.Where(x => x.TableID == tableId && x.rowLabelId == "1");  i think you dont care tableId case sensevity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
List<row> rows_output = rows.Where(x=>x.tableId == "122" && x.rowLabelId == "1").ToList();
```

You need to cast it `.ToList()` 
I prefer strongly typed objects but exchanging `List<row>` with `var` works as well

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows_output = rows.Where(x => x.TableID == "122" && x.rowLabelId == "1").ToList();
```

Comment: You beat me to it :P

Comment: Guys, you really think that `tableID` doesn't exist and he actually should use this constant? Maybe OP should have used this code in his sample to illustrate the problem. But i'm pretty sure that this fixes nothing.

Comment: Where does it says that `tableId` doesnt exists? He clearly says he wants to filter on these parameters, and both @James and i provided with the Linq query. He forgot to cast it to a list at the end, that will have probably screwed things up for not getting back a list in his `var`